# How to properly insulate detached wood garage?

Tags: insulation, garage, siding

I have a wooden detached two car garage that I would like to insulate to eventually convert into a work out space. Currently the walls appear to only be wood siding that has a few gaps in between.

What would be the best route to go, house wrap the outside and add additional vinyl siding, directly insulate against the wood?

[image: inside wall]

Comment: Your general location and/or weather conditions will help.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], please take the [tour]. "Best" invites opinions, and we don't know how you define "best". "What are my options?" is likely too broad. "I'm considering `x` and `y`, what are the pros/cons?" is something we can give a good objective answer to. Please also read up on [how to ask a good question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, it's unclear if you _currently_ have house wrap & vinyl siding on the outside, or if that's part of your proposed insulation plan. I'll note that house wrap and vinyl siding will add roughly R-0.01 to your insulation value. i.e. they're not known for their insulating properties.

Comment: The basic plan is good.  The only thing is how much insulation you need.  Those walls are perfect to add 2x2s or 2x4s for extra insulation depth/better insulation against cold or hot.

Comment: @FreeMan note that house wrap doesn't add insulation, but properly installed it's huge for *air sealing*, which has a big effect on the efficiency of a space.

Comment: Agreed, @KMJ. Just addressing what OP appears to have written...

Comment: Surprisingly a wall like this with just wood, wrap, and siding would have an R-value of about 1.4. Ref: https://www.ahfc.us/iceimages/manuals/building_manual_ap_1.pdf That list does remind one why windows are so awful.

Comment: Windows are a trade off. Really good ones might be R3 or R4, (Absurdly overpriced ones might be R10 when installed, but they'll be R3 or R4 when the fancy gas inside diffuses out over 10 years or so) but having them means the place isn't a depressing dark hole (albeit a better-insulated depressing dark hole.) Few people other than a dedicated agoraphobe (multiple definitions, I'm using the "fear of open spaces" sense) would choose the windowless office over one with a window. If you insulate the rest well, you can afford to have some windows.

Comment: @KMJ, I've always speculated that they use U values to obscure the poor insulation quality. I suppose one of the major benefits of R values is how you can add them when stacking insulation. Maybe that's how they rationalize the obscure rating system.

Answer (score 4):

It's like any open stud wall, which means there are many options, and which one is "best" varies considerably with both climate and budget and the "inital cost .vs. running cost" part of budget (better insulation typically costs more but can reduce the size & cost of the heating/cooling unit you need to buy in the short term, as well as how much that costs to run, over the long term.)

If there are gaps in the boards, those should be repaired, typically. The missing section of stud in the picture should also be repaired, and any similar structural details addressed before you make fixing them harder with insulation and wall finishes.

As you mention potentially re-siding, one common approach in the modern era is to place signficant thickness of board-type insulation on the outside of the wall, where it covers the thermal break of the wooden studs and takes up no additional room inside. You can then add your housewrap and siding over that. In most climates you'll still want insulation in the studbays as well, and more rigid board insulation over the studs on the inside is also an option before drywalling to cover the insulation.

Depending on both climate and insulation costs, sometimes building a whole new non-structural interior wall with studs off-set from the outer wall studs, so you can put in a lot of low-cost loose-fill insulation and not have thermal leak paths at the studs is the best option.

Remember to address any electrical circuit upgrades at the design phase so they can be done at least cost when it's easy, and without disrupting other work after that's done.